# Text overlapping problem

Tags: lettrine, parallel

How can I avoid the text overlapping in the `Parallel` package when using `lettrine`? I am writing parallel text where the left column text translation is written parallel to the right column text. However the text is overlapping when using `letrrine`. I need to use `lettrine` at the beginning of every new chapter number.

Here is my MWE which I have tried so far:

```
\documentclass[twoside,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc} %%% To restart footnote numbering on every new pages
\usepackage{parallel}
\newcommand{\jChapter}[1]{\par\bigskip\lettrine{{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}{}\markboth{\chaplabel\ #1:1}{\chaplabel\ #1:1}\renewcommand{\jnumChapters}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\jverseFormat}[1]{#1}
 \newcommand{\jChapterNumFormat}[1]{\textcolor{cyan}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\jverse}[3]{\noindent{\jChapterNumFormat{#1}\markboth{\chaplabel\ \jnumChapters :#1}{\chaplabel\ \jnumChapters :#1}} #2{\jverseFormat{#3}}\par\smallskip\renewcommand{\jnumVerses}{#1}}
\newcommand{\chaplabel}{}
 \newcommand{\jnumChapters}{0}
 \newcommand{\jnumVerses}{0}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{Parallel}{9.1cm}{9.1cm}
  \ParallelLText{\bf\large\textit{Kethip-ketheng Atomo}}
  \ParallelRText{\bf\large\textit{The Story of Creation}}
  \ParallelPar
\ParallelLText{\lettrine{1}{}{Kechengsi, Arnam sining-heihei lapen pirthe kepinchong ahut,}}
\ParallelRText{\lettrine{1}{}{In the beginning, when God created the universe,}}
\ParallelPar
\ParallelLText{\jverse{2}{}{pirthe arje avelang lapen thangnatta ave, lapen lang-lom athak kangtingsi dolang; lapen Arnam Akarjong lang-heihei athak damlo.}}
\ParallelRText{\jverse{2}{}{the earth was a formless void and darkness covered the face of the deep, while a wind from God swept over the face of the waters.}}
\ParallelPar
\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

Below image is the output of my MWE
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For left text, I have used the `\lettrine` command like this:

```
\ParallelLText{\jverse{}{\lettrine{1}}{}{Kechengsi, Arnam sining-heihei lapen pirthe kepinchong ahut,}}
```

For right text, I have preluded the first letter using,

```
\newcommand \prelude[1] {\makebox[9.4cm][l]{#1}}
```

and used it as follows:

```
\ParallelRText{\jverse{}{\lettrine[ante={\prelude{}}]{1}}{}{In the beginning, when God created the universe,}}
```

where the `9.4cm` value is from your `Parallel` settings (i.e, 9.1cm).

Fullcode:

```
\documentclass[twoside,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc} %%% To restart footnote numbering on every new pages
\usepackage{parallel}
\newcommand{\jChapter}[1]{\par\bigskip\lettrine{{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}{}\markboth{\chaplabel\ #1:1}{\chaplabel\ #1:1}\renewcommand{\jnumChapters}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\jverseFormat}[1]{#1}
 \newcommand{\jChapterNumFormat}[1]{\textcolor{cyan}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\jverse}[3]{\noindent{\jChapterNumFormat{#1}\markboth{\chaplabel\ \jnumChapters :#1}{\chaplabel\ \jnumChapters :#1}} #2{\jverseFormat{#3}}\par\smallskip\renewcommand{\jnumVerses}{#1}}
\newcommand{\chaplabel}{}
 \newcommand{\jnumChapters}{0}
 \newcommand{\jnumVerses}{0}

 \newcommand \prelude[1] {\makebox[9.4cm][l]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{Parallel}{9.1cm}{9.1cm}
  \ParallelLText{\bf\large\textit{Kethip-ketheng Atomo}}
  \ParallelRText{\bf\large\textit{The Story of Creation}}
  \ParallelPar
\ParallelLText{\jverse{}{\lettrine{1}}{}{Kechengsi, Arnam sining-heihei lapen pirthe kepinchong ahut,}}
\ParallelRText{\jverse{}{\lettrine[ante={\prelude{}}]{1}}{}{In the beginning, when God created the universe,}}
\ParallelPar
\ParallelLText{\jverse{2}{}{pirthe arje avelang lapen thangnatta ave, lapen lang-lom athak kangtingsi dolang; lapen Arnam Akarjong lang-heihei athak damlo.}}
\ParallelRText{\jverse{2}{}{the earth was a formless void and darkness covered the face of the deep, while a wind from God swept over the face of the waters.}}
\ParallelPar
\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]